# PHP one-liner to check if any values in array is longer than 5

Tags: php

I want to check **if any values inside my PHP array is longer than 5 words**, using one-liner / simple method.

Output should be a boolean indicating the result.

This is what I come up with:

```php
$isAnyValueTooLong = count(array_filter($array, function ($var)
{
    return strlen($var) > 5;
})) > 0;
```

So it can be used like so:

```php
$array = ["1234", "123456"]; // This should be fail

//$array = ["1234", "1", "123" ]; // This should be OK


$isAnyValueTooLong = count(array_filter($array, function ($var)
{
    return strlen($var) > 5;
})) > 0;

if($isAnyValueTooLong){
  echo "Error, one of the item is longer than 5";
} else {
  echo "Ok, no error";
}
```

However, my method is hard to read and complex. My question is, any **one-liner** to achieve the above requirement?

Performance is not of concern as it is just a simple report program. Thanks.

Comment: I would extract the logic in a very simple and readable form into a method, then call the method when needed. You can also think about making a static helper method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PHP 7.4, you can make use of arrow syntax. Since you're not concerned about the performance.

```
$hasLongString = in_array( true, array_map( fn ($e)=> strlen($e) > 5, $array));
  
  
$output = $hasLongString ? "Found Longer Keys" : "All Good";

OR

$output = in_array(true, array_map( fn($e)=> strlen($e) > 5, $array)) ? "Found Longer Keys" : "All Good";
```

Basically, I am looping through the `$array` to covert the elements to `boolean` and looking for a `true/false` in that.

If you want to go OG.

```
$hasLongString = in_array( true, array_map( function ($e) { return strlen($e) > 5; } , $array));
  
  
if($hasLongString) echo "Oops, found longer key";
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, concise and easily understandable, thanks. We are currently using php 7.2, but will be upgraded to 7.4 soon.

Comment: I've added a solution for older version but I recommend you to upgrade. Glad I could help.